# Show data from many tables in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have tables

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpA 
(
    Type1 Varchar(10),
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Request INT,
    Due INT,
    Month INT    
);

CREATE TABLE #TmpB 
(
    Type1 Varchar(10),
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Request INT,
    Due INT,
    Month INT   
);

CREATE TABLE #TmpC 
(
    Type1 Varchar(10),
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Request INT,
    Due INT,
    Month INT
);

CREATE TABLE #TmpD 
(
    Type1 Varchar(10),
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Request INT,
    Due INT,
    Month INT
);
```

One table represent one month of data which user need to select. User can select for 1 month and also for all 12 months. Here I have taken 4 months data as an example.

I have combined data from different tables into one table. Code as follows:-

```
select *
into #tmpCombine
from  
    (select * from #TmpA union all
     select * from #tmpB union all
     select * from #tmpc union all
     select * from #tmpd) t

select * 
from #tmpCombine
```

Now I want to differentiate data based on month(s). My result set should be like:

[image]

If there are more or less months columns should increase or decrease automatically.

[Code link](http://rextester.com/THP52833)

Thanks

Comment: Creating separate tables for each month's data sounds like a bad idea.  Can you show us the query you used to populate one of those temp tables?

Comment: what query you use to get the results in image?

Comment: @AsifAli72090, I need a query to get result, for which I post the image

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry, I can't post that query but I have used while loop to get each month data.

Comment: Can I ask the reason why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You have a *really* bad data model, as Tim points out in a comment.  You should be storing all the data in a single table.  Using multiple tables is generally a really bad idea.

But you have the notion of `union all`ing them together.  The next step is a pivot, which you can do using `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select type1, col1,
       max(case when month = 1 then request end) as request1,
       max(case when month = 1 then due end) as due1,
       max(case when month = 2 then request end) as request2,
       max(case when month = 2 then due end) as due2,
       max(case when month = 3 then request end) as request3,
       max(case when month = 3 then due end) as due3,
       max(case when month = 4 then request end) as request4,
       max(case when month = 4 then due end) as due4
from (select * from #TmpA union all
      select * from #tmpB union all
      select * from #tmpc union all
      select * from #tmpd
    ) t
group by type1, col1;
```

Your coding question suggests that you are (way) overusing temporary tables when writing queries.  If so, you need to learn more about CTEs and subqueries.  On rare occasions, temporary queries can improve performance.  In most cases, they hurt performance by introducing unneeded writes and reads and prevent the optimizer for finding the most efficient query plan.